# Cups failing with Samsunc C430W networked printer

Tags: printing

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.2 on an Acer laptop. I installed cups and told it I had a Samsung C430W laser printer on an Ethernet connection. I was referred to an HP page for finding a .ppd file for this printer, which I duly downloaded it as a zip file containing an install.sh script. This ran without problems.

In cups (with cups-brosered enabled and unarmor blocked, I see the printer listed as a network printer. I select it specifying that it should be ipp:<the 192.168 address of the printer>

cups administer printer lists the printer twice:

Samsung_C43x_Series Samsung C43x Series     Samsung C43x Series Idle - "Nothing to print"

Samsung_C43x_Series_SEC30CDA7B52CA4 Samsung_C43x_Series_SEC30CDA7B52CA4     Samsung C43x Series, driverless, cups-filters 1.28.15   Idle - "Printer disappeared or cups-browsed shutdown"

When I select the fist printerr: Samsung_C43x_Series and use the management button to select print test page, these are the log files - flat text pastebin files

/var/log/cups/access.log: https://pastebin.com/aPzzQy78

/var/log/cups/error.log: https://pastebin.com/4E4qDp3g